# Empty header tags

Tags: headers

[image: Problem]

When I set the 'posts for page' option to a specific page, then that page gets an empty header and the page is not structured.

The site has a customized theme of twenty eleven.
Could someone point me into a direction of a possible solution?

How it should be:
[right display](http://www.kornuyt.nl/blog/)

NOTE: its not online visible, because of debugging services

Comment: Looks like you have some syntax error, otherwise the text above the image wouldn't be visible.

Comment: The errors shown in the console are no syntax errors. I have seen this before, but then it was caused by the css, this time not. I haven't yet found any syntax error.

Comment: Is this a custom theme? If so, have a look at the template page where that comment is supposed to be and check it is correct?

Comment: As far as I have seen nothing changes if the option is used or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be missing the opening `<?php` or else that text shouldn't be readable above the image. The file seems to be using index.php but it's possible depending on your theme setup that it's a different file missing the `<?php`. Therefore, get_header() is not filling the header at all, because it's displaying as HTML instead of acting as PHP.

Comment: In the code, `<?php` is there at the beginning in most files, haven't yet checked them all. If I do not set the 'posts for page' option, the get_header() function is working normal.

Comment: Have you checked index.php? `<?php` needs to go in the index.php (or whatever page is creating that output) right before that extra text displaying at the top of your screenshot. It's possible that `<?php` is there but is followed by a `?>` which is closing the php section. You need to be sure `<?php` is open right before those comments and the get_header() call.

Comment: Specifically this will only be in the theme php files (or child theme if it's a child theme) and not anywhere else in WP.

Comment: I hadn't checked the index.php yet. I wanted to check that file as last, but WordPress turned the `<?php` into something else in that file. For now it seems to be the solution. Thanks a lot Ambroseya.